# Unable to run Android4.4 in Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: android, virtualbox, whatsapp

I was successfully running Android4.4 on Oracle VM VirtualBox without any problem.
However today when I started Android I am just getting the screen where it shows Android is loading. [image]

I haven't deleted any files. 
But I notice in settings that their is a Snapshot folder. I am unable to locate this folder in my hard drive. 
[image]
Can this be a problem?

I ran Android on debug mode and it is working now. But WhatsApp was installed inside Android and now it is not their. All the files related to WhatsApp are still present but the app is missing.
Can i restore WhatsApp to what it was before?
[image]

Comment: Try restarting your Ubuntu